# Tkinter radiobutton strange appearance

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a `Radiobutton` set using a class but all buttons are checked at the beginning

When I tried to enter a variable for `Radiobutton` at its creation phase I got an error message.

```
from tkinter import *

SubTests = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4', 'Test 5', 'Test 6', 'Test 7', 'Test 8', 'Test 9', 'Test 10']

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master=NONE):
        self.master = master
        rb = [NONE]*len(SubTests)
        for i in range(len(SubTests)):
        rb[i] = Radiobutton(master, text=SubTests[i], fg='black', value=i)
        rb[i].grid(column=0, row=(2 + i), sticky=W, padx=5)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('940x550')
root.resizable(FALSE,FALSE)
root.title("GUI Template")

display = GUI(root)

root.mainloop()
```

There should appear a `Radiobutton`s Test1, Test2, ..., Test10 unchecked, but instead of they're all checked.

Comment: Your question is unclear and ambigious. what actually the problem in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to set up the buttons as well as an `IntVar` variable I've named `choice` to hold a value corresponding to the `Radiobutton` currently "pushed in" (if any). I also made it and the `rb` list instance attributes of the `GUI` class instance by prefixing them with `self.`. This will make it possible to refer to them from other methods of the class since all methods are automatically passed `self` as their first argument.

To demonstrate how these instance attributes could be used, the code also utilizes the `command=` option that `Radiobutton`s have to specify a "callback" function to be called every time the user changes its state.

```
from tkinter import *

SubTests = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4', 'Test 5', 'Test 6', 'Test 7',
            'Test 8', 'Test 9', 'Test 10']

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.choice = IntVar(value=-1)  # Set to a value no button will produce.
        self.rb = []
        for i, subtest in enumerate(SubTests):
            radio_btn = Radiobutton(master, text=subtest, fg='black', value=i,
                                    variable=self.choice, command=self.btn_callback)
            radio_btn.grid(column=0, row=i+2, sticky=W, padx=5)
            self.rb.append(radio_btn)

    def btn_callback(self):
        choosen = self.choice.get()  # Index of button pressed.
        subtest = self.rb[choosen].cget('text')  # Button's text.
        print('You chose: {}'.format(subtest))


root = Tk()
root.geometry('940x550')
root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
root.title("GUI Template")

display = GUI(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This won't work - for radiobuttons to be radiobuttons (ie: an exclusive choice) they need to share a single variable, but you're giving each one a separate variable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Bryan. I've updated my answer according.

Comment: One comment in your code is a bit misleading. There’s nothing special about the value -1, other than no buttons have that value. Any number not represented by a button will cause them all to be deselected.

Comment: Is there a way from main program's body to select a specific button using variable created in class GUI?

Comment: panlam: Not sure what you mean by "from main program's body". Anyway, you can set (turn on) the `i`th button by calling `display.rb[i].select()` and you can call `display.rb[i].invoke()` to get the same actions that would occur if the user clicked on it.

Comment: @Bryan: Well -1 _is_ special in the sense that it's a value that could not be the result any of the buttons being pressed. However, based on your feedback, I've changed the comment slightly to avoid giving anyone the wrong idea.

Answer (score 0):

Radiobuttons need to have the `variable` attribute set to an instance of one of tkinter's variable objects (`IntVar`, `StringVar`, etc). Tkinter uses the fact that multiple radiobuttons share the same variable to give them their exclusive choice behavior.

Since you are using integer values, you can use an `IntVar`. You need to create that variable outside of the loop, and use it inside the loop. The following code creates a single variable (`self.var`), and associates it with each radiobutton (`variable=self.var`)

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master=NONE):
        self.master = master
        self.var = IntVar(value=0)
        rb = [NONE]*len(SubTests)
        for i in range(len(SubTests)):
            rb[i] = Radiobutton(master, text=SubTests[i], fg='black',
                                value=i, variable=self.var)
            rb[i].grid(column=0, row=(2 + i), sticky=W, padx=5)
```